# Visual Studio online insufficient privileges when creating a release definition

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a release definition in Visual Studio Online with the task  `"Deploy Azure App Service"`.

When I try to authorize for the subscriptions it gives this error message below.

```
Error(s):
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. For troubleshooting refer to <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=835898" target="_blank">link</a>.
```

[image: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation message]

The content of the link they provide doesn't seem to help me.

I already tried this using Azure Service Administrator account.

Why is this happening? What are the kind of permissions i need for doing this?

Comment: What's the result if you configure it manually?

Comment: Do you check this point: The user is not authorized to add applications in the directory (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/azure-rm-endpoint#insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation)

Comment: You sad that you've already tried this using Azure Service Administrator account, is this member in the Global Admin role in the directory. (You must be a member of the Global Admin role in the directory in order to create an Azure Resource Manager service endpoint)

Comment: @starain-MSFT Yes that was the issue. The user account that i used for doing this wasn't a Global Administrator in the AD. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user must be a member of Global Admin role in the directory.

On the other hand, you may configure it manually with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-documentation/blob/master/Azure/SPNCreation.ps1) PowerShell script.

More information, you can refer to [Automating Azure Resource Group deployment using a Service Principal in Visual Studio Online: Build/Release Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/) (Manual configuration section)

> Download & run this PowerShell script in an Azure Powershell window to
>   generate required data for Service Principal based Azure service
>   connection. Running this script would prompt you for:
>
> The name of your Azure Subscription name
>
> A password that you would like to set for the Service Principal that is going to be created
>          Note: the script has been tested with Azure PowerShell version 1.0.2.
>
> Once successful, the script would output the following details for the
>   Azure Service Endpoint.
>
> Connection Name
>
> Subscription Id
>
> Subscription Name
>
> Service Principal Client Id
>
> Service Principal key
>
> Tenant Id